# how to use BIDS to show SSRS report from Window form

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer, bids

Hello friends I want to display SSRS report in my local Window form.
IN report viewer i don't want to display it from URL. I want to show reports without deplyoing it.

Can anyone give me idea for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it after a longtime.

this way i am calling remote report to local machine and use it on windows form as on web.

```
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = textBox2.Text;
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your Report Viewer control to use Local Processing.  Be aware that this does change the behavior of the control, as it removes the need for a Report Server.  See this page for tips on getting started, and some of the pitfalls to watch out for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251704.aspx

Comment: thanx kyzen but in local processing in this way

"Report parameters in client report definitions (.rdlc) do not map to data source query parameters. "

This will be totally different then SSRS functionality.

Comment: Yes - when using reports in local processing mode, your application is expected to provide the data to the rdlc.  If you *must* use SSRS reports, but don't want to deploy the reports to an SSRS server and run them from there, then this is kind of what you're stuck with.